# Can I create triggers in the database?

Tags: wordpress, error, database

We are trying to setup CiviCRM in Wordpress.

Our Database is on GoDaddy, but we are running into a problem:

"Could not create a database trigger."

The Database Settings appear to be correct.

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question with what versions of Wordpress and CiviCRM you're using. No need to mention what host you are on. When you created the database to be used for CiviCRM, you need to make sure your database user has the permission for database triggers.

Comment: It does help to mention the host, b/c the host (in this case GoDaddy) will not let you have the perms you need to create triggers. I found that problem w/a couple of other hosts. GD is one that won't let you create triggers, if you're using shared hosting there.

Answer (score 1):

If the Setup Screen tells you that the database settings are correct, it means you can login into the database with the username and password that you entered. However, it does not guarantee that the MySQL database user has enough privileges to perform all necessary database actions.
CiviCRM needs *trigger support* and in the System Administrator Guide at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-permissions is described what this entails.

If you are not able to grant the correct privileges in the control panel of your internet service provider, you have to contact their service desk.

Answer (score 1):

This occurred to me too, my website was hosted with godaddy, i contacted them and they refused to allow 'Triggers' privileges on database while website is hosted with GoDaddy shared hosting plan. So i had to shift to [iPage](http://www.ipage.com/) which allows the required privilege.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to create triggers and stored procedures in shared hosting and might need to move to a cloud. I remember having these issues on godaddy too and moved to Ubuntu cloud. Call them and check. As I recall as a DBA you cannot create these without the super user privilege which isn’t possible in shared environments

Answer (score 0):

Usually cheap hosting costs you more in the longer run. There are some civi-specific hosting providers (CiviHosting springs to mind) & using one of them will make you less sad